# Information About UUID

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I am developing an Android app which connects to device. Here, I have few very basic questions about UUID which I need better understanding.

1). Is UUID specific to each device(.i.e provided by the manufacture of that device) or is it something of a Unique String for each device( when connecting multiple devices) which can be assumed randomly or ?

2). Is there a category of UUID's for different category types of devices like a set for mobiles,laptops,etc and a different set of UUID's ranges for printer, scanner,etc?

3) And how many UUID's are required for connecting each device. I mean for example, All-in-one printer has both printer and scanner in it and if we need to use both of them, do we need 2 UUIDs for the same device or the number services running on that device(device) and also?

4) How do we find number of services running, which can be connected through Bluetooth, on the remote device( like printer here)(For this Q, I guess providing link is appropriate)

And also, any additional info I need to know about UUIDs, please add that too.
(Please explain little before posting links)

Thank You Guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.UUID is specific for each device .Refer [1](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/util/UUID.html),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964342/android-how-do-bluetooth-uuids-work),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457175/android-bluetooth-uuid-connecting-app-to-android) for details.